# How to transfer text from one phone to another via NFC in react-native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, nfc, ndef

I am making a react-native demo in which I want to transfer string data from one android/ios device to another android/ios device and use that string data.

I have searched alot but did not found anything which is useful. Some of the article says that peer to peer data sharing is not doable as of now. Please let here know with any possible way to transfer string via NFC.
some links.
[https://github.com/revtel/react-native-nfc-rewriter/issues/6#issuecomment-826286515](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/67401609](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Not really possible as there is no solution with NFC for the combination of ios device to ios device.

Android Beam (peer to peer) was Android to Android only and was removed in Android 10

If one of the devices is Android then you can still use Host Card Emulation (HCE) but you need to write Native Java/Kotlin for that and it's complicated.